# Is there a way to prevent code comments to be marked as changes in the diffs obtained from version control? (CVS/SVN)

Tags: svn, version-control, cvs

Is there a way to prevent code comments to be marked as changes in the diffs obtained from version control? (CVS/SVN) I hate the differences showing 100's of changes when there are only a handful due to the update in the comments for CVS info like log or id.

Comment: Don't use the log keyword.  It's a disaster and it only replicates information otherwise obtainable by your SCCS.  In factthe Subversion developers refused to allow it: http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#log-in-source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might come down to answering another question:

[Is it useful to have versioning information like history log and file ID on the source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128913/is-it-usefull-to-have-versioning-infor-like-history-log-and-file-id-on-the-source)

Answer (score 2):

Comments themselves would be counted as changes - however you could run the code through a code beautifier of sorts (to remove comments or other things according to your own rules) before committing to trunk, and then the diff between trunks would only show code changes rather than the comments on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

How could you expect a source control system to store a new version of the file and then ignoring the fact it has stored a new version?

Comment: I'm not expecting it to be ignored. I want to ignore those when doing the diff. i'll clear up my question. I understand the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so. Because SVN doesn't/can't understand what is into a file. It just show you what is into the file.

Answer (score 0):

I use a diff program like Beyond Compare that can ignore whitespace and comment changes, but only when doing diffs. However if the file actually changed, then most vcs would list that in their changelist. In SVN you could engineer a commit hook that detects if a chagne is "significant" according to your rules. It could then reject the commit if the chagne is not.